# Meaning of "100 Ironman-Length Triathlons"

Tags: meaning-in-context

The headline is:

> He Felt Like Running: 100 Days, 100 Ironman-Length Triathlons

the source:

[NY Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/06/28/sports/iron-cowboy-endurance.html)

What did the author mean by: '100 Ironman-Length Triathlons'?

is it about a runner in a race designed for 100 Triathlons? OR about a runner who is behind
100 Triathlons? OR even about something intirally different?

I read the article but it was still dubious for me.

Comment: It means: he ran 100 ironman triathlons in 100 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple. The guy did the equivalent of an Ironman level triathlon every day for 100 days. The [Ironman triathlon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironman_Triathlon) consists of a 2.4 mile swim, a 112 mile bike ride and a full marathon run.